# Shared nuget.config

Tags: nuget

Is there an option to define a shared nuget.config?

A company wide nuget.config stored on a network drive that all computers access.

Without the need to push this file to all computers locally, and to easier maintain changes that should be applied company wide eg. new package source, or package mapping.

Comment: Company wide project template is the way to go. nuget.config is part of a project, similar to .csproj or other project files.

Comment: @Jacek - `Company wide project template is the way to go.` but I can't specify, eg. `packagesources` in eg. `directory.build.props` or can I?

Comment: @Jacek - I am stating `directory.build.props` because for a shared `build.props` I am using the `Import` task https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/import-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022

Comment: @Jacek - okay, after some thought - I believe you mean if a user created a new solution with the "company wide project template" it would create a nuget.config additionally to the "normal" files, and this nuget.config has the "company" settings included, am I correct? if so, sadly thats not what I am looking for because if I want to change the nuget.config, I would need to hunt down every old nuget.config and replace it. as I said, I would like to have it shared to easier maintain changes that should be applied company wide. eg. every developer in the company should access same package source

Comment: I see. I'm afraid it's not possible without some hacking. Technically what you want to do is to run a job that configures the nuget before build start. Such a job would need to be committed to the common repository so that it works for each developer. Depends on how you perform the build, you can try with MsBuild Copy target in `directory.build.props` that copies nuget.config from shared location to the project root folder. Or a custom target that invokes a .bat file with a series of `nuget.exe config -set ...` CLI commands. Assuming that nuget exists in each developer's PATH...